# Problema instalar flask-mysqldb sobre linux 16.04

Tags: mysql, python, flask, mysqldb

Estaba intentando instalar el flask-mysqldb en mi dispositivo Linux 16.04 pero encontré un problema, incluso con un entorno virtual: `_mysql.c: 32: 20: error fatal: Python.h: No existe ese archivo o directorio`.

```
(myFlaskAppenv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp$ python -m  pip install flask-mysqldb
Collecting flask-mysqldb
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/e3/955c845efe1aacf30c8e2607470544ede36aa1044f6382c809f13e014104/Flask-MySQLdb-0.2.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in ./myFlaskAppenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from flask-mysqldb) (1.0.2)
Collecting mysqlclient (from flask-mysqldb)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/86/bad31f1c1bb0cc99e88ca2adb7cb5c71f7a6540c1bb001480513de76a931/mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in ./myFlaskAppenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in ./myFlaskAppenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in ./myFlaskAppenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in ./myFlaskAppenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (6.7)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./myFlaskAppenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (1.0)
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient, flask-mysqldb
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/myFlaskAppenv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-rpj3mj09/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-r7zvujiv/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/myFlaskAppenv/include/site/python3.5/mysqlclient:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,12,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.12 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/myFlaskAppenv/include -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/_mysql.o
    _mysql.c:32:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/myFlaskAppenv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-rpj3mj09/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-r7zvujiv/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/myFlaskAppenv/include/site/python3.5/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-rpj3mj09/mysqlclient/
```

¿Qué puedo hacer entonces para instalarlo?

Tengo python3 :

```
(myFlaskAppenv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
```

Comment: ¿Tienes [python3-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python/python3-dev) correctamente instalado? `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

Comment: @FJSevilla Si, al menos Python 3.5.2 cuando hizo `python -V`

Comment: No me refiero a `Python3` como tal sino al paquete **`python3-dev`** que contiene **archivos de cabecera y librerías estáticas** necesarias entre otras cosas para **compilar extensiones en C (Python/C Api)**, el error se debe a que el compilador gcc es incapaz de encontrar el archivo de cabecera `Python.h`, lo cual puede estar causado por una instalación defectuosa del paquete mencionado.

Comment: @FJSevilla Ok. En este caso, lo desinstalo y lo vuelvo a instalar en el entorno a través de `python -m pip install python3-dev`?

Comment: No, es un **paquete del sistema** no un paquete Python, prueba a instalarlo con `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`, no debería haber problemas si está correctamente instalado. El archivo `Python.h` debería localizarse en  `/usr/include/` para que el compilador no tenga problemas en localizarlo, en tu caso en `/usr/include/python3.5m` si no me equivoco.

Comment: @FJSevilla, si, perfecto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para compilar módulos escritos en C usando la [API Python/C](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/) se necesitan un conjunto de archivos de cabecera y librerías estáticas, siendo imprescindible el archivo de cabecera `Ptyhon.h` (`#include "Python.h"`), que incluye todas las definiciones de función, tipos y macros necesarias para usar la API.

El error en este caso se debe a que el compilador de C (gnu-gcc) no es capaz de encontrar `Python.h` en el proceso de compilación de `_mysql.c`. La ruta especificada en el Makefile es `/usr/include/python3.5m` en este caso, ruta donde no encuentra el archivo de cabecera.

Hay veces que esto ocurre porque a pesar de tener los ficheros de cabecera, estos se encuentran en un directorio diferente al especificado en los *include* del *Makefile*, por ejemplo  `/usr/local/include/python3.5m`, en estos casos podemos solucionarlo de forma simple creando un link.

En este caso concreto lo que seguramente ocurre es que no está instalado correctamente el paquete **[python3-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python/python3-dev)** que contiene los ficheros de cabecera y bibliotecas estáticas necesarios para compilar o desarrollar extensiones usando la *API Python/C*. En el caso de Debian/Ubuntu lo podemos instalar con:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```